# This relative module was not found, when importing typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js

**Preemptive note:** There are a ton of "relative module was not found" questions on Stackoverflow. I have looked through as many as I could find and they are not duplicates. Please don't mark this as a duplicate.

I have a Vue project set up with `vue create` that uses Babel and Typescript, I then generated some gRPC-Web / Protobuf code with this command:

```
cd src
protoc -I=../../protos ../../protos/foo.proto --js_out=import_style=typescript:. --grpc-web_out=import_style=typescript,mode=grpcweb:.
```

This generated these files in the `src` directory:

- `foo_pb.d.ts` (the Typescript definitions for the Protobuf messages)
- `empty.js`, `memory.js` (the Protobuf messages)
- `FooServiceClientPb.ts` (the gRPC-web code)

However when I `npm run serve` or `npm run build` I get this error:

```
This relative module was not found:

* ./foo_pb in ./src/main.ts, ./src/FooServiceClientPb.ts
```

In both `main.ts` and `FooServiceClientPb.ts` it does this:

```
import {Empty, Memory} from './foo_pb';
```

I can ctrl-click `./foo_pb` and it opens `foo_pb.d.ts` correctly, so VSCode at least knows how to open that file. And all the files are in the same directory! Why can't the build system find it?

I've tried the standard delete `node_modules`, get a lawyer, hit the gym. Also `npm-check-updates -u`. Nothing works.

### Edit 1

I got a bit further by adding a `console.log()` in the bit where the error is generated (apparently Vue doesn't output the actual error, yeay). I got this:

```
resolve './foo_pb' in '/home/me/myproject/src'
  using description file: /home/me/myproject/package.json (relative path: ./src)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    using description file: /home/me/myproject/package.json (relative path: ./src/foo_pb)
      no extension
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /home/me/myproject/src/foo_pb doesn't exist
      .mjs
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /home/me/myproject/src/foo_pb.mjs doesn't exist
      .js
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /home/me/myproject/src/foo_pb.js doesn't exist
      .jsx
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /home/me/myproject/src/foo_pb.jsx doesn't exist
      .vue
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /home/me/myproject/src/foo_pb.vue doesn't exist
      .json
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /home/me/myproject/src/foo_pb.json doesn't exist
      .wasm
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /home/me/myproject/src/foo_pb.wasm doesn't exist
      .ts
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /home/me/myproject/src/foo_pb.ts doesn't exist
      .tsx
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /home/me/myproject/src/foo_pb.tsx doesn't exist
      as directory
        /home/me/myproject/src/foo_pb doesn't exist
```

If you run `vue ui` and check out the `Inspect` task (the resolved webpack config) you see:

```
  resolve: {
    extensions: [
      '.mjs',
      '.js',
      '.jsx',
      '.vue',
      '.json',
      '.wasm',
      '.ts',
      '.tsx'
    ],
    ...
```

Note that it is missing `.d.ts`. So I tried adding it, by creating a file `vue.config.js` with this content:

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    resolve: {
      extensions: [
        ".d.ts"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

However this doesn't work either:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                                                                                                                                 12:36:53

 error  in ./src/foo_pb.d.ts

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Thread Loader (Worker 0)
Debug Failure. Output generation failed
    at PoolWorker.fromErrorObj (/home/me/myproject/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/WorkerPool.js:262:12)
    at /home/me/myproject/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/WorkerPool.js:204:29
    at Object.transpileModule (/home/me/myproject/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:112341:29)
    at getTranspilationEmit (/home/me/myproject/node_modules/ts-loader/dist/index.js:283:74)
    at successLoader (/home/me/myproject/node_modules/ts-loader/dist/index.js:66:15)
    at Object.loader (/home/me/myproject/node_modules/ts-loader/dist/index.js:22:12)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I *think* this is just a bug in `protoc`. I was running it like this:

```
protoc -I=../../protos/ ../../protos/foo.proto --js_out=import_style=typescript:. --grpc-web_out=import_style=typescript,mode=grpcweb:.
```

That creates `foo_pb.d.ts` but it *should* create `foo_pb.js` too. In fact it creates separate files for each message - `memory.js` and `empty.js`. I "fixed" it by running this command:

```
protoc -I=../../protos/ ../../protos/foo.proto --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:. --grpc-web_out=import_style=typescript,mode=grpcweb:.
```

This then generated the `foo_pb.js` file, and *it also generates the `foo_pb.d.ts` file*. I know right, WTF?

Comment: `--js_out=import_style=typescript:.`   is not supported. What you did here `--js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:. --grpc-web_out=import_style=typescript,mode=grpcweb:.` is correct. Overall, typescript support is experimental right now. The standard `protoc` does not support `--js_out` for typescript output for now. So as an experimental feature, the `--grpc-web_out` plugin is temporarily outputing .d.ts for the protobuf messages.

Comment: So surely `--js_out=import_style=typescript` should produce some kind of error if it isn't supported?Anyway I've made [a pull request to clarify things in the readme](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/pull/646).