# vue-cli-service verbose build mode

Tags: vue.js

vue-cli-service is giving me some [nonsense typescript error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58198496/this-relative-module-was-not-found-when-importing-typescript), but it's really hard to track down because it doesn't tell me what commands it is actually running. Is there a verbose mode for `vue-cli-service build` that will tell me what it is doing in detail?

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Unfortunately this does not exist because it does everything in Javascript (a good design). I ended up adding `console.log()` in lots of places inside the `vue-cli-service` source code.

Comment: `everything in Javascript (a good design)`. Wow, you said that with a straight face and everything.

Comment: What do you mean? It's much more robust to do everything via Javascript than through files and shell commands. It's faster, no need to deal with quoting issues, errors are reliably propagated, if you do it properly and use Typescript then you get type checking, etc. Definitely a better design. They just need to add better logging.

Comment: Can't leverage multiple cores because it's Node (w/o implementing hacks). Not sure why you say it's more robust and I'm not sure why you would rely on shell commands as an alternative. _Why_ is it more robust? Because of error propagation and quoting? So, you wouldn't be able to implement a JS parser/compiler in any other language? That seems like an odd claim. I'm a big fan of JS but relying on JS/Node is not necessarily good design just by default. Also, I'm not sure what to make of your somewhat contradictory claim that "does not exist because JS" but also "good design b/c JS".

Comment: It's more robust because you don't convert everything to/from strings all the time. "you wouldn't be able to implement a JS parser/compiler in any other language?" not sure what you're talking about; I never said that. "somewhat contradictory claim", it's not contradictory. Good design is not one-dimensional. You can use a good design and then forget to implement an important feature. It does not make it a bad design. Node has been able to multiple threads for quite a while.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand why you think it's good design to use Javascript. I mean why not Rust? Seemed like a weird claim to make when answering the question w/o justification. So it's a good design decision because you don't have to convert strings? Maybe explain a little. Convert strings to objects and then back for emission? Someone coming here who might not understand what all these js tools/builders/etc are doing would need more info. Parsers/compilers are a core function of code transformation tooling.

Comment: Oh right, I didn't mean it is better to use Javascript than Rust, Go, etc. I meant it's better than the traditional thing of running commands via `system()` or similar. I think I've explained why about 3 times now. Passing data through the string-based interface that `system()` requires is very error prone and discards all static type information.